# Sitecore - build URL with Agent

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

I have an Email sending class, when the activate the item it generates a link to the dash board as follows,

`Item dashboardItem = DatabaseManager.WebDatabase.GetItem"/sitecore/content/Public/Pages/Users/Dashboard");
            string url = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(dashboardItem, opt);`

URL generated as `http://mysite/Pages/Users/Dashboard`, which is the expected behaviour. This is the user accessible URL.

I am trying to generate the same Email using a scheduled task. But when it runs and tries to execute this code URL generated as follows,

`http://127.0.0.1/sitecore/content/Public/Pages/Users/Dashboard`

Seems like when we are using the scheduler LinkManager can not identify the URL mapped with the item. How can I generate the user accessible URL with the scheduled task?

Comment: I am not a sitecore expert but i think it is probably not picking up the site context in the scheduled task so it is just returning the full sitecore path to the item.

Answer (score 5):

This happens because the scheduled task is running in a different SiteContext.

In the code of your task, you should manually switch to the SiteContext that contains the item you are linking to.

In such way:

```
using (new Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextSwitcher(
         Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext.GetSite("your_site_name")))
{
    // load item & generate url here ...
}
```

`your_site_name` is the site name that is configured in the `<sites>` configuration.